# Do I need to stop service started by startWakefulService

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

My app handles GCM broadcast and start a IntentService to handle it. The service is started by calling startWakefulService. At the end of onHandleIntent, PushNotificationReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent) is called.

But, do i need to call stopService or stopSelf to stop the service? If I need to do it, what is the best place to call it? It seems the GCM example doesn't stop the service. Does it stop itself?

Comment: Can you show us what code you've got so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to stop the IntentService.

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html):

> IntentService is a base class for Services that handle asynchronous requests (expressed as Intents) on demand. Clients send requests through startService(Intent) calls; the service is started as needed, handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and **stops itself when it runs out of work**.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I missed the last bit of that paragraph.